# one of which will be/is and the other will/is

Tags: verbs

Suppose that you have put a few boxes on a table. Each box contains a watch and one more thing. The surprise item is different in each one. You let your friend choose a box and keep the gifts inside. This what you are going to say to him/her.

(1) Each box has two items, one of which **is** a watch and the other **is** a mystery.

(2) Each box has two items, one of which **will** **be** a watch and the other **will be** a mystery.

(3) Each box has two items, one of which **will** **be** a watch and the other **is** a mystery.

I am not sure which verb form is correct? Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

The first part of the sentence is in simple present tense, then why use future tense for the other part, when referring to the same thing?

> **Each box has two items, one of which is a watch and the other is a mystery.**

would be correct.

If you want to use future tense, I'd suggest to use it in the following way:

> Each box will have two items, one of which will be a watch and the other will be a mystery.